# Warlock and Sorcerer Multiclass Casting With An Enhanced Effect

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, multi-classing, sorcerer

I have a multiclass PC with 3 levels in warlock/hexblade and 1 level in sorcerer/divine soul.

This means I have 2 level 1 sorcerer slots and 2 level 2 warlock slots. I can cast *cure wounds* because I am a good aligned divine soul sorcerer.

If I cast *cure wounds* using a level 2 warlock slot, do I heal for 1d8+CHA or 2d8+CHA?

Comment: Related: [What level are spells cast at if a warlock multiclasses as another caster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59288/33707)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### 2d8 + CHA modifier

The description for [Cure Wounds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cure-wounds) includes:

> At Higher Levels: When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 2nd level or higher, the healing increases by 1d8 for each slot level above 1st.

You are casting the spell at 2nd level, using a 2nd level slot. The fact that you can only cast 1st level sorcerer spells is irrelevent.

Therefore, the spell will heal 2d8+CHA modifier hit points.

Comment: To the person who downvoted this: why? This answer is just as good as the other one, and came first as well.

Comment: Some people see the early answers in a different order, so what may have happened was that someone perceived that this answer came after the other one.  People are not required to comment on down votes, so I'd not expect an answer to that. (you got my up vote: helpful, correct, concise).

Answer (score 21):

## It would be 2d8+CHA modifier

from the Multiclass rules on pg 164 of the PHB:

> **[Pact Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting)**. If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the
>   spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you
>   know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class
>   feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the
>   Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.

Casting of a higher level [Cure Wounds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cure-wounds) gives you the extra 1d8 per slot:

> At Higher Levels: When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 2nd
>   level or higher, the healing increases by 1d8 for each slot level
>   above 1st.