# What are the pros and cons of a Hexblade dip for a Paladin/Sorcerer multiclass?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, multi-classing

I am building a paladin/sorcerer multiclass character that's focused on nova damage, using sorcerer spell slots to fuel Divine Smites. My current plan is something like Paladin 6/Sorcerer 14, in order to get the Aura of Protection.

I've been thinking about adding a level of warlock (hexblade) after Paladin 6 but before taking sorcerer levels. Because my STR is 16 and my CHA is 20 (lucky roll + ASI), the Hex Warrior feature would basically be an effective +2 weapon, and the spell slot, cantrips, and curse would be nice too. However, this level comes at the cost of delayed progression and eventual sorcerer levels.

Are there other pros or cons of this dip that I'm missing? Is it a good idea in general? An ideal answer would be from someone who's played a build like this, although I would also appreciate a detailed analysis of the two options. Additionally, since I'll be playing this character from early to late levels, it would be nice to have an analysis of intermediate levels, not just at level 20.

Comment: Whether something is "worth it" is entirely opinion-based...

Comment: @V2Blast While there is definitely some opinion in this question, I was hoping the relatively narrow build criteria I set would help provide more "objective" standards. Do you think this reformulation is better?

Answer (score 7):

## Yes

If you are taking any significant number of Sorcerer levels, it is *always* worth dipping a level of Warlock (regardless of the sort) [because this decouples your level and your spells-per-day](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106255/is-it-possible-to-charge-up-a-sorcerer-warlock-by-taking-multiple-short-rests) by allowing you to substitute time for being a much higher level in terms of the number of slots available to you.  In my experience, having vastly more (albeit lower level) spell slots is hugely valuable for most characters and worth the single level of delayed progression. This is *even more* true of a Paladin/Sorcerer multiclass focusing on burning slots to power smites, as (in my experience) you never have as many low level slots to burn as you'd like.  The ability to charge up before you start nova-ing means you can probably nova at the level of burning your highest level spell slots for an entire adventuring day before you run out, assuming you travel between adventures and locations within an adventure on the scale of days or weeks.

So, regardless of whether taking hexblade also boosts your melee combat competency directly more than the 14th level Sorcerer origin ability of whatever origin you pick does unless that origin involves open-ended spell slot accumulation a level in Hexblade is better.

Comment: You should mention that warlock slots come back after a short rest, and thus give you more sustainable fuel.

Comment: @BladeBriar That's literally the whole crux of my answer.  You can short rest to get slots as a Warlock, which you burn into Sorc slots so you can short rest again.  Any suggestions on how to make that clearer?