# D&D 5e Warlock Multiclass - Casting Warlock Spells Using Other Class Spell Slots

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, multi-classing

If I'm playing a level 5 character with **Spellcasting** and multiclass to gain level 1 *Warlock* gaining **Pact Magic**, can I use my primary spell slots to cast my Warlock spells?

For example, is casting *Hex* using one of my 3rd level slots allowed?

Comment: Hi Pyrox, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. If I understand correctly, you're asking whether someone would learn Hex via multiclassing -- and also, separately, what level they could/would cast it at. (Possibly up to 5th as well, for example.) Is that accurate?

Comment: The wording on the question is confusing, specially the later phrase. "Can for example Hex then cast as a lvl 1 or 3rd lvl spell?" - do you mean to ask if you can cast Hex with the spell slots from the 5th level caster?

Comment: As per @OneCritWonder edition, the question is now clear, but I hope this is indeed the intent from OP. If it isn't, let's just expect him to change it back, I guess.

Answer (score 12):

### You can choose either.

This is covered on the multiclassing section (p. 164) of the Player's Handbook or [the Basic Rules here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) (***emphasis*** mine):

> **Pact Magic.**
>    If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the spellcasting class feature, and ***you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know***.

Comment: Hmm, interesting reading here: it says you can use the spell slots from Pact Magic to cast the spells from the other class, but it does not say that you can cast the spells you know from Pact Magic using the spell slots from the Spellcasting, or did I miss something?

Comment: @HellSaint rest of the quote had it

Comment: @pyrox it is usually best not to ask questions in comments but it turns out that has already been asked [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45750/41726)