# Spells cast using Pact Magic slots recovery

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, rests, spell-slots

If a wizard 4/warlock 2 were to cast Shield using a warlock spell slot. Would the character regain the ability to cast it again on a long rest or short?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG.SE! Which game and edition are you playing?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Multiclass Warlock Sorcerer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45750/multiclass-warlock-sorcerer-how-do-spell-slots-recover)