# How does the Land Druid's Natural Recovery feature interact with the Warlock's Pact Magic spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, druid, multi-classing, spell-slots

Do the Natural Recovery ability of the Land Druid and Pact Magic of the Warlock work together?

I am planning to create a D&D 5E character that can recover spell slots easily, at least during short rests. I am thinking of multiclassing the character. Say I used both a druid and warlock spell slots in an encounter, and then we took a short rest after. Does this work?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Could you clarify what you mean by whether Natural Recovery and Pact Magic "stack"? What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Multiclass Warlock/Sorcerer: How do spell slots recover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45750/multiclass-warlock-sorcerer-how-do-spell-slots-recover)? Though that other question doesn't cover features like Arcane Recovery and Natural Recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sort of, but not as well as you might like.

The first thing to understand is that Warlock Pact Magic doesn't stack with other kinds of casting.  If you have a character who has 3 levels in druid, and 3 levels in cleric, they have the spell slots of a 6th level character.  (Their spells known only go up to spell level 2, but they can upcast.)  if you have someone who has 3 levels in druid and 3 levels in warlock, they will cast pact magic with the slots of a 3rd-level warlock.  They will also cast druid magic with the slots of a 3rd-level druid.  If they've cast out of pact magic slots, and they short rest, they get back all of those pact magic slots, as warlocks do.  If they've cast out of druid slots and they short rest, they can use Natural Recovery to recover some of those slots... as long as they haven't exhausted their ability to use Natural Recovery for the day.  However, their ability to recover druid slots on a short rest doesn't benefit in any way from their warlock levels.

It is the case that as a multiclassed druid/warlock, you can cast spells off your druid list using your pact magic slots (which you can then recover on a short rest) as long as the level of your pact magic is high enough to cast the spells in question.  That has nothing to do with Natural Recovery, however.  Likewise, you can cast warlock spells off of druid slots, if you wish to do so.

As a further warning, this character is likely to be frustratingly weak, compared to party members who pick a casting class (or non-casting class) and stick with it.  in 5th ed, multiclassing is usually a mistake, unless you can find a combination that works particularly well together for some reason.  In the case of Druid/Warlock it's particularly bad because the druid craves Wisdom and doesn't care about Charisma, while the warlock craves Charisma and doesn't care about wisdom.  If you want a caster who runs on short rests, play a warlock.  Possibly talk with your DM about adjusting the spell selection, to allow more druidic spells via pact magic, and go pact of the tome so you can pick up some druid cantrips.  If you want to play a druid, play a druid.  The Natural Recovery of a pure druid will be much more effective than the Natural Recovery of a Druid/Warlock multiclass.  There will be more druid levels to power it, after all.  If you want to play a druid that mostly runs on short rest resources, consider playing a Circle of the Moon druid, and focusing on shapeshifting.  Natural recovery is nice, but it isn't that big a deal.  It's basically one more casting of whatever your highest level spell slot is.

Comment: While you correctly describe most of how multiclassing with Warlock levels works, I think you're a little misleading about how spells slots can be *used* by such a character. You can use your spell slots from either class to cast any of the spells you know. So if you have 2 level 2 warlock spell slots, you can use them to cast druid spells, and then gain them back after short rest.

Comment: Does someone have a reason for the downvote?

Comment: @Blckknght fair point.  I added a paragraph expressing that, and, after further thought, modified the misleading text in the first paragraph.  I hadn't intended to mislead.  I'd honestly forgotten that they could cross-cast like that.  Fixed now, regardless.

Comment: I think the answer would also be improved by citing/pointing out the relevant rules (i.e. the multiclass spellcasting rules, and the relevant Land druid and warlock class features).

Answer (score 4):

#### In short, yes.

All spellcasting classes apart from warlock have the Spellcasting feature
while warlocks get the pact magic feature -

> The Warlock table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your warlock spells of 1st through 5th level. The table also shows what the level of those slots is; all of your spell slots are the same level. To cast one of your warlock spells of 1st level or higher, you must expend a spell slot. You regain all expended spell slots when you finish a short or long rest.

Classes with the spell casting feature normally only regain their spell slots on a long rest with a few of them having a few features to regain the spell slots sooner. In the case of Land Druids as per Natural Recovery -

> Starting at 2nd level, you can regain some of your magical energy by sitting in meditation and communing with nature. During a short rest, you choose expended spell slots to recover. The spell slots can have a combined level that is equal to or less than half your druid level (rounded up), and none of the slots can be 6th level or higher. You can’t use this feature again until you finish a long rest.

which allows you to regain spell slots on a short rest. There is no conflict between the two abilities and they would allow you to use a lot more spells through the day.

If you are interested in other classes/features that allow you to recover spell slots between long rests you can look at the **Font of Magic - Flexible Casting** feature of sorcerers and the **Arcane Recovery** feature of wizards. All of these features are independent of each other and will stack, but keep in mind that the amount of spells that you can recover is limited by your level in the class which grants the feature.

Answer (score 2):

They don’t interact or interfere with each other at all.

Before Natural Recovery (I.e. normally), your Pact Magic spell slots refresh on a short or long rest, and your Spellcasting spell slots refresh on a long rest only.

Once you get Natural Recovery, your Pact Magic spell slots still refresh on a short or long rest - nothing changes there - but your Spellcasting spell slots refresh completely on a long rest (as normal) and partially on a short rest (due to Natural Recovery).

Comment: Note that the number of spell slots recovered by Natural Recovery during a short rest is limited. (It does not recover all missing spell slots)